# Could not GET 'google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml'.Received status code 502 from server:Bad Gateway

Tags: android, flutter

I get this error while trying to debug my flutter app.

```
> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml.
 > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml'.
  > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I was able to debug the code till last night, No code changes are made.

I tried changing gradle version but nothing works.

current gradle and gradle plugin version used :

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0  //in build.gradle
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip // in gradle-wrapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google bintray is down. And any plugins depending on this will try to communicate with https://google.bintray.com/ thus throwing this error.

It worked for me by upgrading all the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

to synchronize the gradle use a vpn in some occasions it becomes complicated without using these